# Can missing two oil changes cause piston rings to crack?

Tags: scheduled-maintenance, piston, rings

Car is 4 cylinder Astra.  !.4 engine no turbo charge.  Last service 8500kms.  Missed 2 services, rings in number two piston failed at 44000kms.  Oil level always maintained.  Car only driven on sealed roads.  Would missing 2 services cause rings to fail?

Comment: Was there still oil in the engine?

Comment: Hi Bob,  there was still oil in the engine and it appeared clear just a little darker than new.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not but if you are looking to make a warranty claim and you did not follow the recommended service intervals, then they can probably deny the claim as there is some relation to engine oil changes and a problem with piston rings.

Comment: That is exactly what they did saying "suspect" cracked rings due to missed services.  They did no further investigation and relied on Holden telling them not to do anything.  My guess is that Holden said that because if there was a fault the dealer could claim from Holden.  Just leaves the little guy out in the cold.  Can you explain further the relationship to serving and the rings please?

Comment: If you neglect the oil changes then it's possible that the oil's lubricating properties were diminished and/or there was excess contaminants in the oil.  These can cause excess friction on the rings which can lead to damage.  There is, in my view, a possible causal relationship between missed oil changes and your ring damage.  It's a strong enough relationship that they are likely within their rights to deny the claim.  Sorry, but that's the way I see it.

Comment: Thank you.  Can you recommend an expert who could give a written opinion?

Comment: No, I'm not able to make such a recommendation, you may want to seek one in your local market.  Perhaps an independent mechanic who can evaluate your vehicle and determine the actual cause of whatever issues you are having.  There are some relatively simple and inexpensive tests to confirm or rule-out a piston ring issue.  This question, however, underlines the importance of following the recommended service intervals to protect your warranty coverage.  You don't need to use the dealer's service, but you do need to do the work.